# Bash - Send commands to a CLI

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a script in bash (on Linux) and I need to send some commands to a command line interface but I don't know how to do it.

To open the CLI :

```
myserver# ovirt-shell [options]
```

Then I'm in a new shell where I execute some commands to get back informations :

```
[oVirt shell (connected)]# list hosts > hosts.txt<br>
[oVirt shell (connected)]# list vms > vms.txt
```

So I would like to execute ovirt-shell and send my commands (list vms/hosts) directly in my script, in "silent-mode".

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the program reads from stdin, you can pipe the commands to stdin:

```
ovirt-shell <<EOF
list hosts
list vms
EOF
```

An alternative is to store the commands in file and execute it like this:

```
ovirt-shell -f filename
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I forgot to say that to access to this shell, I need to enter a password, how can I give it in my script ?

Comment: It depends. Multiple ways can be used, from passing it on the command line (considered insecure), using `expect` or simply piping it to stdin like the commands itself. None of them is really secure since all require to write down the password somewhere. I personally don't know ovirt-shell, but probably it offers ways for passwordless authentication. If not, you'll need to pick one out of the other alternatives I've named before.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There is a way to call rhevm-shell passwordless, by adding the password in the .rhevmshellrc. This file is created at the first start of rhevm-shell in the directory where there is the certificate to connect to the engine (.crt).

Comment: You are welcome! Utilizing `.rhevmshellrc` sounds like the way to go here. Make sure that only your user is allowed to read the file.

Comment: Does the '<<' operator just pipe to stdin until it hits the 'EOF' identifier? I need my script to run more commands after I disconnect from the CLI, so that can't be the end of file for me.